# Scheduled publishing

Tags: scheduled-tasks, module

I tried to schedule the item in schedule publishing using Sitecore publishing module. But, after scheduling the item, I manually published the item but it is still showing in schedule publishing queue. is there any reason behind this?

I downloaded the Sitecore schedule publish package from market place. SITECORE SCHEDULED PUBLISH

I installed this on a Sitecore 8.2 update 3 instance. I set a publishing schedule on a single item.

Comment: Hi @Akshay, welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. This question may be better suited as a question on the site https://Sitecore.chat; your question may require more dialog than is appropriate for SSE. If you feel your question still needs to be posted here, please provide more details about how you setup the scheduled publishing (with screenshots and steps outlined) as well as what you have tried and which versions of Sitecore products/modules you have installed.

Comment: I have updated my question.